# Querying django ManyToMany

Tags: django, models, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have got

`Foo` <=> `FooGroup` <=> `Bar`

relation, where `<=>` stands for ManyToMany field.

How do I retrieve all the `Foo`s for a specific `Bar` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example with auth models, where the relationship is very much like your structure : User <=> Groups <=> Permission

```
from django.contrib.auth import models
models.Permission.objects.filter(group__user=models.User.objects.get(username="webmaster"))
```

With your example:

```
Foo.objects.filter(foogroup__bar=barinstance)
```

Comment: Thank you. Got hard time thinking mondays :)